# Differences in equation of moments.

Tags: calculus, centroid

Context: http://archives.math.utk.edu/visual.calculus/5/work.2/

The formula in question:

$$\mathbf{M}_{x}=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\rho}{2} \left \{ \left [ f\left ( x \right ) \right ]^{2} - \left [ g\left ( x \right ) \right]^{2}  \right \}dx$$

Questions:

- Why $\rho$ is divided by 2 **and** $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are squared?
- Why is $\mathbf{M}_{x}$ different from $\mathbf{M}_{y}$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moments are actually computed from double integrals, which can be integrated first on $y$:

$$\int_{x=a}^b\int_{y=f(x)}^{g(x)}\rho x\,dy\,dx=\int_{x=a}^b\rho xy\Big|_{y=f(x)}^{g(x)}\,dx=\int_{x=a}^b\rho x(g(x)-f(x))\,dx$$and
$$\int_{x=a}^b\int_{y=f(x)}^{g(x)}\rho y\,dy\,dx=\int_{x=a}^b\rho\frac{y^2}2\Big|_{y=f(x)}^{g(x)}\,dx=\int_{x=a}^b\rho\frac{g(x)^2-f(x)^2}2\,dx.$$

The asymmetry comes from the fact that the domain is delimited by two explicit curves $y=f(x),y=g(x)$.

Similarly, the expression of the mass is obtained from
$$\int_{x=a}^b\int_{y=f(x)}^{g(x)}\rho \,dy\,dx=\int_{x=a}^b\rho y\Big|_{y=f(x)}^{g(x)}\,dx=\int_{x=a}^b\rho (g(x)-f(x))\,dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 
$$
M_y = \int_a^b \rho y\left(f(x) -g(x)\right)dx
$$
Now we have

$$
y = f(x)\\
y = g(x).
$$
So mean value gives
$$
y = \frac{f(x) +g(x)}{2}
$$
Subbing in for $y$ in the integral yeilds the desired result.